# Swift: get index of start of a substring in a string

Tags: string, swift, indexof

Is there a way to search a string for the index of the start of a substring?

Like, `"hello".indexOf("el")` would return 1. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach using the `rangeOfString` function that finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within a given range like in the following way:

```
var text = "Hello Victor Sigler"

if let indexOf = text.rangeOfString("Victor")?.startIndex {
   println(indexOf) //6
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: In Swift 5 this throws a `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` error for `startIndex` (tested in Playground).