# swift 3 get start index (as int) of substring

Tags: swift, indexing, substring, swift3

I would like to get the start and end position of a substring within a string. Example: in the string "hi this is my name"; if I provide the string "this" I would like to know the start index is 4 and end index is 7.

I found several links, including this one:

[Swift: get index of start of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105260/swift-get-index-of-start-of-)
a-substring-in-a-string

But it doesn´t work in swift 3 as the method is now called range.

I am now using this:

```
let range = mystring.range(of: "StringSearch")?.lowerBound
```

which returns this

```
Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 15), _countUTF16: 1))
```

And I cannot obtain the position as an integer as this is an index.

In summary, I would like to have in a variable of type int the position, in this case 15.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: In what unit do you want that indexes, Characters, UnicodeScalars or UTF-16 code units?

Comment: All relevant methods of `String` to split strings into substrings expect this index type. If you need the `Int` index to use the `NSString` methods. get rid of `NSString`

Comment: Hi. I would like to have the position (above 15) in a var of type int so I can use in another method. I needed something like lowerbound.position

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`distance(from:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1782684-distance) method of `String` computes the difference
between two `String.Index` values:

```
let mystring = "hi this is my name"
if let range = mystring.range(of: "this") {
    let startPos = mystring.distance(from: mystring.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
    let endPos = mystring.distance(from: mystring.startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
    print(startPos, endPos) // 3 7
}
```

Actually it just forwards the call to the string's `CharacterView`, so 
the above gives the same result as

```
let mystring = "hi this is my name"
if let range = mystring.range(of: "this") {
    let startPos = mystring.characters.distance(from: mystring.characters.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
    let endPos = mystring.characters.distance(from: mystring.characters.startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
    print(startPos, endPos) // 3 7
}
```

---

If you need *all* occurrences of the string:

```
let mystring = "this is this and that is that"
var searchPosition = mystring.startIndex
while let range = mystring.range(of: "this", range: searchPosition..<mystring.endIndex) {
    let startPos = mystring.distance(from: mystring.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
    let endPos = mystring.distance(from: mystring.startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
    print(startPos, endPos)

    searchPosition = range.upperBound
}
```

Comment: What if there is one more "this" and you want to find second "this"s start and end index?

Answer (score 3):

Adapted answer from Martin R into a function gives you the first occurrence as an `NSRange`. You could turn this into an `extension` of `String` also.

```
public class func indexOf(string: String, substring: String) -> NSRange? {
    if let range = string.range(of: substring) {
        let startPos = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        return NSMakeRange(startPos, substring.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: What about returning a simple Int ?

Comment: Missing a return if substring is not found.