# Format String left of multiple characters in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have some Strings that vary in length but always end in "listing(number)"

`myString = 9AMnep8MAziUCK7VwKF51mXZ2listing28`

.

I want to get the String without "listing(number)":

`9AMnep8MAziUCK7VwKF51mXZ2`

.

Methods I've tried such as `.index(of: )` only let you format based off one character. Any simple solutions?

Comment: What about using a regex: `let regex = try! NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "(.*?)(listing\\d+)", options: []); let newStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count), withTemplate: "$1")`?

Comment: Yeah, regex is what I was going to suggest too.

Comment: Is there possibility that there would be more than one `listing` in the initial string?

Comment: Yes, there is a answer that works with any number after "listing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to search for the substring with Regular Expression and remove the result (replace it with empty string)

```
let myString = "9AMnep8MAziUCK7VwKF51mXZ2listing28"
let trimmedString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "listing\\d+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

- `\\d+` searches for one ore more digits
- `$` represents the end of the string

Alternatively without creating a new string

```
var myString = "9AMnep8MAziUCK7VwKF51mXZ2listing28"
if let range = myString.range(of: "listing\\d+$", options: .regularExpression) {
    myString.removeSubrange(range)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the simple answer I've been looking for. Worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to split the string in parts with "listing" as separator

```
let result = myString.components(separatedBy: "listing").first
```

Answer (score -1):

So to solve your issue find the code below with few comments written to try and explain each steps have taken. kindly note i have modified or arrived at this solution using this links as a guide.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070835/6596443
2. https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-swift

   ```
   extension String {
       //
       // Paramter  inputString: This is the string you want to manipulate
       // Paramter- startStringOfUnwanted: This is the string you want to start the removal or replacement from
       //return : The expected output you want but can be emptystring if unable to

       static func trimUnWantedEndingString(inputString: String,startStringOfUnwanted: String) -> String{
           //Output string
           var outputString: String?
           //Getting the range based on the string content
           if let range = myString.range(of: startStringOfUnwanted) {
               //Get the lowerbound of the range
               let lower = range.lowerBound
               //Get the upperbound of the range
               let upper = range.upperBound
               //Get the integer position of the start index of the unwanted string i added plus one to ensure it starts from the right position
               let startPos = Int(myString.distance(from: myString.startIndex, to: lower))+1
               //Get the integer position of the end index of the unwanted string i added plus one to ensure it starts from the right position
               let endPos =  Int(myString.distance(from: myString.startIndex, to: upper))+1
               //Substract the start int from the end int to get the integer value that will be used to get the last string i want to stop trimming at
               let endOffsetBy = endPos-startPos
               //get thes string char ranges of values
               let result = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)..<myString.index(myString.endIndex, offsetBy: -endOffsetBy)
               //converts the results to string or get the string representation of the result and then assign it to the OutputString
               outputString = String(myString[result]);
           }
           return outputString ?? "";
       }
   }
   let myString = "9AMnep8MAziUCK7VwKF51mXZ2listing28"
   String.trimUnWantedEndingString(inputString: myString, startStringOfUnwanted:"listing")
   ```

Comment: Kindly provide a feedback and not just down vote. let me know why you feel the approach is wrong. don't down vote answers without giving a feedback or improving the solution. thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote, but two much simpler solutions were posted and an answer was already over a day prior ~ I assume that is why you got downvoted.

Comment: oh okay great, i even upvoted the simpler solution after i submitted and noticed it.